# How to recursively copy arrays

Tags: javascript, recursion

I want to recursively produce the vertices (points) of a unit n-hypercube (for the sake of clarity, just a cube here). The idea is to specify the points of the cube by recursively going through the x, y, and z components. Why not just use nested for-loops? Recursion is intrinsically swag. This is my function:

```
var points = [];

function makeCube(d, point) {
  console.log(d,point);
  
  if(d == 0) {
    points.push(point);
  } else {
    extension1 = [...point];
    extension1.push(0);

    extension2 = [...point];
    extension2.push(1);
    
    makeCube(d - 1, extension1);
    makeCube(d - 1, extension2);
  }
}
```

I call `makeCube(3, [])`. The console reads this:

```
[Log] 3 – [] (0) (sketch.js, line 57)
[Log] 2 – [0] (1) (sketch.js, line 57)
[Log] 1 – [0, 0] (2) (sketch.js, line 57)
[Log] 0 – [0, 0, 0] (3) (sketch.js, line 57)
[Log] 0 – [0, 0, 1] (3) (sketch.js, line 57)
[Log] 1 – [0, 0, 1] (3) (sketch.js, line 57)
[Log] 0 – [0, 0, 1, …] (4) (sketch.js, line 57)
etc...
```

When d is 1, there should only be 2 entries in the array, not 3! When d is 0, there should be 3, not 4. The second array in the lowest level is being carried up a level somehow. I made a point of copying the extension arrays rather than setting them equal to the old one, so I don't understand what's going on.

Expected console output:

```
[]
[0]
[0,0]
[0,0,0]
[0,0,1]
[0,1]
[0,1,0]
[0,1,1]
[1]
[1,0]
[1,0,0]
[1,0,1]
[1,1]
[1,1,0]
[1,1,1]
```

Comment: can you write what the output exact output should be for `d = 3`?

Comment: @Mulan d = 3 is the top level of recursion, so the array is empty: []. If you meant d = 0, then that is every combination of three 1s and 0s.

Comment: somehow that seems backwards, but okay. can you please write out the *exact* output in the question?

Comment: Ok, I just added the full expected output to the end of the question.

Comment: [...point] is shallow copy. Try `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(point))`

Comment: Good point but I still get the same output. I think that shallow vs deep copy doesn't make a difference for an array of primitive type.

Comment: When answering what the value should be for "d=3" you *say* an empty array but *show* an array with 4 entries. The question was what the output should be for an input of 3. Which should we believe? What should the return value of "makeCube(3, [])" be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I solved the problem:

```js
var points = [];

function makeCube(d, point) {
  console.log(d, JSON.stringify(point));
  
  if(d == 0) {
    points.push([...point]);
  } else {
    let extension1 = [...point];
    extension1.push(0);

    let extension2 = [...point];
    extension2.push(1);
    
    makeCube(d - 1, extension1);
    makeCube(d - 1, extension2);
  }
}

makeCube(3, [])
```

```
3 []
2 [0]
1 [0,0]
0 [0,0,0]
0 [0,0,1]
1 [0,1]
0 [0,1,0]
0 [0,1,1]
2 [1]
1 [1,0]
0 [1,0,0]
0 [1,0,1]
1 [1,1]
0 [1,1,0]
0 [1,1,1]
```

I just added `let` twice (and changed what I logged).
The original script creates global `extension1` and `extension2` variables in the window. Apparently, the global scope caused some problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generator to move the side effect, `console.log`, outside of the function. This also makes it easy to skip the global `points` variable. Use a `for..of` loop to iterate through all the points -

```js
function* makeCube(d, point = []) {
  yield point
  if(d == 0) return
  yield *makeCube(d - 1, [...point, 0])
  yield *makeCube(d - 1, [...point, 1])
}

for (const point of makeCube(3))
  console.log(`(${point.join(",")})`) // caller decides effect
```

```
()
(0)
(0,0)
(0,0,0)
(0,0,1)
(0,1)
(0,1,0)
(0,1,1)
(1)
(1,0)
(1,0,0)
(1,0,1)
(1,1)
(1,1,0)
(1,1,1)
```

Or use `Array.from` to collect all of the points into an array

```js
const points = Array.from(makeCube(3))

console.log(points)
```

```js
[
  [],
  [0],
  [0,0],
  [0,0,0],
  [0,0,1],
  [0,1],
  [0,1,0],
  [0,1,1],
  [1],
  [1,0],
  [1,0,0],
  [1,0,1],
  [1,1],
  [1,1,0],
  [1,1,1],
]
```

If you want to compute the `product`, I would suggest you write the function somewhat differently -

```js
function* product(t, ...more) {
  if (t == null) return yield []
  for (const p of product(...more))
    for (const v of t)
      yield [v, ...p]
}

for (const p of product([0,1], [0,1], [0,1]))
  console.log(p.join(","))
  
for (const p of product(["J", "Q", "K", "A"], ['♡', '♢', '♤', '♧']))
  console.log(p.join(""))
```

```
0,0,0
1,0,0
0,1,0
1,1,0
0,0,1
1,0,1
0,1,1
1,1,1
```

```
J♡
Q♡
K♡
A♡
J♢
Q♢
K♢
A♢
J♤
Q♤
K♤
A♤
J♧
Q♧
K♧
A♧
```

Comment: I think the OP wants [0,0,0], [0,0,1], ... (those with 3 elements) but not the intermediate steps that has less elements (like [], [0], [0,1]). 
It's easy to filter the results by length, but is there a way that never pushes the intermediate steps?

Comment: I thought that at first too but the updated question shows the expected output, which matches this answer.

Comment: In the OP, `points.push(point)` only happens for `d==0`, though, so I think he only wanted to store the result of maximum recursion.

Comment: If the OP's code does not produce the explicitly stated expected result, I think it's safe to assume the code is wrong. I updated my answer to include a `product` function which performs more like you suggest.

Comment: This answer is also great. @qrngsky is correct, I only wanted to return the length-3 arrays, but I logged all of them for debugging purposes. Anyway, thanks a heap.

Comment: You're welcome :D In the future, always provide the expected output of the function in question. I mean the `return` value or desired effect, not the `console` output.